# What are the Leftmost and Rightmost nodes of a Binary Tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

Given the following Binary Tree, what is the "leftmost" and "rightmost" node?

I read that `inOrder` traversal tells us what the leftmost and rightmost nodes are,
`preOrder` tells us the rightmost node, `postOrder` tells us the leftmost node, and levelOrder tells us the rightmost node. However, the traversals for this tree are:

```
const inOrder    = [4, 7, 2, 1, 8, 5, 3, 9, 6];
const preOrder   = [1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 8, 6, 9];
const postOrder  = [7, 4, 2, 8, 5, 9, 6, 3, 1];
const levelOrder = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Which gives my conflicting information. So clearly for one or more of these traversals there should be an * saying *only for a Perfect Binary Tree*. But I am unsure which is correct. Do we call Node 4 the leftmost node or Node 7? Do we call Node 6 the rightmost node or Node 9?

[image: binary tree]

Comment: Usually the terms "leftmost node" and "rightmost node" are relative to a *level* in the tree, not the tree as a whole. What is your source?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know! I wrote down some notes last week and cannot find where I read it. I think it was someones comment on a LeetCode question. So I suppose that the only statements that can be made are that `levelOrder` traversal tells us the rightmost node. All of the statements I referred to are only applicable when the tree is Perfect (full and complete).

Comment: There is no way to answer this question (what are the leftmost and rightmost nodes of a binary tree). There is no official definition, so a source is needed. You might even have misread or misunderstood, who knows...? Like I said above, code challenge sites like [GfG](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/leftmost-and-rightmost-nodes-of-binary-tree/1) or [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/670480/curefit-right-most-node-in-last-level-of-complete-binary-tree) use the term in the context of a *level*.

Comment: The simplest definition of leftmost would be to go left until you can no longer go left (4), similarly for rightmost (6).